# format string to XML to include tabs, line breaks etc

Tags: c#, string, xml-serialization

I am serializing a string from a multiline text box to an XML. Is send the line breaks and tabs to save in the XML so when I deserialize it, I get it back looking the same?

Example - The textbox will look like:

```
Hello JohnDoe,

     This is a message
...
Somelines....

Thank you,
...
End
```

When I serialize this and then deserialize it, the textbox gets populated like:

```
Hello JohnDoe,This is a message..Some lines....Thank you,...End
```

It doesn't have to be really pretty, I'm just trying to come up with a good way to get it back in a better format. Thanks.

Okay so the code i have is as follows:

```
public void SerializeToXML(List<Report> newReport)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Report>));

            //XmlWriterSettings serializer_settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            //serializer_settings.Indent = true;
            //serializer_settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;

            TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(xmlPath);
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, newReport);
            textWriter.Close();
        }
```

Where `Report` is just a class with some string attributes. The commented lines are somethings I was trying to accomplish my goal.

Report class code:

```
public class Report
    {
        public string name
        { get; set; }

        public string email
        { get; set; }

        public string defectID
        { get; set; }

        public string fixedBuild
        { get; set; }

        public string description
        { get; set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public string messageBody
        { get; set; }

     private static readonly XmlDocument _xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

     [XmlElement("messageBody")]
     public XmlCDataSection TextCData
     {
         get
         {
             return _xmlDoc.CreateCDataSection(messageBody);
         }
         set
         {
             messageBody = value.Data;
         }
     }
    }
```

the output remains the same (no whitespace formatting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to preserve all whitespace in your XML is to use a `CDATA` section. The details depend on the way you do your serialization. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103749/maintain-whitespace-line-breaks-when-serializing-via-net-web-service) for an explanation in a web service context. If you serialize manually, use [`XmlWriter.WriteCData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writecdata.aspx) method.

Comment: hmm okay i've edited my class to use the CDATA formatting. no change on the output. any ideas?

Comment: i'm also thought that the issue may be stemming from the fact that i am deserializing the XML to a LIST, then the textbox (because there is more than one report in the XML. but viewing the XML file itself (before it is deserialized, i see that the formatting is still omitted).

Comment: @ikathegreat If CDATA section does not appear, the changes you made are not correct. Try writing a tiny self-contained test project that writes a single element to XML with a CDATA section in it. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379888/how-do-you-serialize-a-string-as-cdata-using-xmlserializer) for additional information on how to do it. Try the second (not accepted) answer first, then the accepted one if that does not work.

Answer (score 1):

This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256097.aspx) seems to offer a valid solution. Also check out this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265966/xml-carriage-return-encoding).

Hard to give good advice without seeing your code.

**EDIT**

You could add it [manually](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.xml.aspx).

Or you might be able to get by with something like this (untested, modified from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012360/how-to-add-attributes-for-c-sharp-xml-serialization)):

```
public class Report
{
    [XmlAttribute("xml:space")]
    public string spacing = "preserve";
}
```

this way it should get added automatically during serialization. However, if you can figure out a way to set an XmlAttribute that's not based off a field or property, that would be even better.

Comment: to preserve the white space, one of the articles suggests `xml:space="preserve"`. I'm not sure where this goes or how to get it in the XML...? During serialization?